# is it possible to generate Visual Studio solution files using StylusStudio?

Tags: visual-studio, projects-and-solutions, solution

i was wondering if it is possible to generate some kind of template that i give an xml or xsl file in stylus and generate  c# code

i made some .cs and works fine, but i couldn't with csproj and sln files,

so, thats why i am asking

i used to program dlls on c# 
is a n-tier programming

Comment: What are you getting at? Why do you want to create a sln files with an XML tool instead of VS itself or a meta builder like cmake or premake? Maybe edit your question in order to explain the rationale in order to get better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Stylus Studio](http://www.stylusstudio.com/) includes both XSLT and XQuery, and with either you can write text files. So you can manually write a `.sln` file, if you have the proper source - because `.sln` files are not XML. Project files, like `.vbproj` or `.csproj`, are XML and can easily be created by Stylus Studio.

Is that what you are asking?

If you have a XSLT or XQuery program, you can choose to generate code to drive that transform. It will create a Visual Studio project for you. For XQuery, it will use the .Net Saxon XQuery engine. For XSLT, several different XSLT engines for .Net are supported.

Use the "XQuery > Generate Code > Generate C# Code..." or "XSLT > Generate Code > Generate C# Code..." options to actually create the code and attendant `.sln` file.

If however, you do want for some reason to use XSLT inside of Stylus Studio to create a .sln file, here is how you might go about it.

Sample input file:
    
    
        FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC
        
            Watchdog
            DB3FBB37-100C-40DD-B154-153E3F3A68FF

Sample XSLT file to create `.sln` from above `.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:text>&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 10.00&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text># Visual Studio 2008&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="projects/project" mode="a"/>
        <xsl:text>Global&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>&#9;GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>&#9;&#9;Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>&#9;&#9;Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>&#9;EndGlobalSection&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>&#9;GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="projects/project" mode="b"/>
        <xsl:text>&#9;EndGlobalSection&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>&#9;GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>&#9;&#9;HideSolutionNode = FALSE&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>&#9;EndGlobalSection&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>EndGlobal&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="project" mode="a">
        <xsl:text>Project("{"</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="../guid"/>
        <xsl:text>}") = "</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
        <xsl:text>", "</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
        <xsl:text>\</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
        <xsl:text>.csproj", "{</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="guid"/>
        <xsl:text>}"&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>EndProject&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="project" mode="b">
        <xsl:text>&#9;&#9;{</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="guid"/>
        <xsl:text>}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>&#9;&#9;{</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="guid"/>
        <xsl:text>}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>&#9;&#9;{</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="guid"/>
        <xsl:text>}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>&#9;&#9;{</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="guid"/>
        <xsl:text>}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

[John is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122632/is-it-possible-to-generate-visual-studio-solution-files-using-stylusstudio/1122681#1122681), you'd be better off using notepad, but there is a [free version of Visual Studio 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/express/) that you can use to create many types of solution if you don't want to invest in a license.  If you're trying to do template driven code generation, have a look at [CodeSmith](http://www.codesmithtools.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio solution files are not XML, so I wouldn't expect Stylus Studio to do much with them.

Snippet of a solution file:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 10.00
# Visual Studio 2008
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "HttpsUrlWithPort", "HttpsUrlWithPort\HttpsUrlWithPort.csproj", "{9FD67B56-9D49-4989-89D0-06A29ACAA5A3}"
EndProject
```

Comment: I'm not sure what StylusStudio is but I do believe that Visual Studio Solution files are in an XML format.

Comment: @NotDan: You are thinking about project files.

Answer (score 0):

A: Use t4!

Visual Studio's T4 Code Generation 
create templates using Microsoft's T4 templating language.

Q: I want to generate some of the code for my application and Microsoft has a code generator, t4.

A: Microsoft has a code-generation tool T4 which stands for Text Transformation Templating Toolkit.

T4 comes with Visual Studio 2008, or you can download it if you're using VS 2005.